# How to define if variation in a single data set is significant

Tags: statistical-significance

I have a (small) sequence of numbers from tests involving various null hypotheses. The resulting numbers display some variation which is quite small though. What is the simplest way to define if this variation is statistically significant or not? I can compute the mean and the SD, but how can use these numbers to get the answer?

Comment: You should provide more information on your data (how much data you have? Is it discrete or continuous?) and the statistical framework you want to use. Also, what are your null-hypotheses?

Comment: The question is unanswerable as posed. Statistical significance requires some sort of hypothesis. So, for instance, you might want to compare the SD of these data to the SD of some other data, or some theoretically derived values or something else.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to clarify. Suppose I have a big data set, and I have found a certain pattern within it. Then I want to test several alternative hypotheses explaining how this pattern might have originated. In each of this test I get the probability of getting this pattern provided that the particular hypothesis is true. Say, I have a dozen of alternative hypotheses, so I have a dozen of numbers representing these probabilities, and I want to know if the difference between them is significant.